# How can I perform a Head request using mechanize in Ruby

Tags: ruby, mechanize-ruby

I can perform a `HEAD` request with Faraday (Faraday.head url), but I am using Mechanize on my current project.

I would like to grab a value from the header (filename) without downloading the file. Does the Mechanize gem provide such an option? I am using v2.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like `get` but it's `head` instead:

```
page = agent.head 'http://www.google.com/'
page.body.length
#=> 0
page.header.keys
#=> ["date", "expires", "cache-control", "content-type", "set-cookie", "p3p", "server", "x-xss-protection", "x-frame-options", "transfer-encoding"]
```